# How to read a JSON file in powershell and assign the array elements to a new json objects?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a JSON file

```
{
  "appname": "apple",
  "category": "fruit",
  "buildapp": [
    {
      "workdir": "work1",
      "tesdir": "test1",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value1",
        "set2": "value2"
      }
     },
     {
      "workdir": "work2",
      "tesdir": "test2",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value3",
        "set2": "value4"
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

I want to read the buildapp section and assign the first section of array to a new JSON object and second section to another JSON object and it has to go on dependending on the number of array sections

```
expected ouput would be 
variable     Value
------------------
appname = apple
category = fruit
buildapp.workdir1 (JSON object that holds the array element)  =
 {
workdir : work1,
tesdir: test1,
setdata: {
  set1: value1,
set2: value2
}
} 
buildapp.workdir2 (JSON object that holds the array element)  =
 {
workdir : work2,
tesdir: test2,
setdata: {
  set1: value3,
set2: value4
}
}
```

I know how to read individual elements but not how to assign a complete array element to another object

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78070252/edit) your question to provide the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
# Read the JSON file
$json = Get-Content -Raw -Path 'Desktop/example.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Create an array to store the objects
$objects = @()

# Iterate over the buildapp array
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $json.buildapp.Count; $i++) {
    # Create a new object for each array element
    $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "appname" = $json.appname
        "category" = $json.category
        "buildapp.workdir$($i + 1)" = $json.buildapp[$i]
    }
    # Add the object to the array
    $objects += $object
}

# Output the objects
$objects

$jsonFilePath = 'Desktop/result.json'

# Convert to json
$jsonObjects = $objects | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

# Write to json file
$jsonObjects | Out-File -FilePath $jsonFilePath
```

This will result in JSON file like this:

```
[
  {
    "appname":"apple",
    "category":"fruit",
    "buildapp.workdir1":{
      "workdir":"work1",
      "tesdir":"test1",
      "setdata":{
        "set1":"value1",
        "set2":"value2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "appname":"apple",
    "category":"fruit",
    "buildapp.workdir2":{
      "workdir":"work2",
      "tesdir":"test2",
      "setdata":{
        "set1":"value3",
        "set2":"value4"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

...or something like this if you need to have only one object in resulting JSON that has as many properties as `buildapp` array:

```
$buildAppWorkdir = @{}

# Iterate over buildapp array and add them to map
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $json.buildapp.Count; $i++) {
    $buildAppWorkdir["buildapp.workdir_$($i + 1)"] = $json.buildapp[$i]
}
...
# need to change object to save to json file
$jsonObjects = $buildAppWorkdir| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Resulting JSON file will look like this:

```
{
  "buildapp.workdir_1":{
    "workdir":"work1",
    "tesdir":"test1",
    "setdata":{
      "set1":"value1",
      "set2":"value2"
    }
  },
  "buildapp.workdir_2":{
    "workdir":"work2",
    "tesdir":"test2",
    "setdata":{
      "set1":"value3",
      "set2":"value4"
    }
  }
}
```

You can add other properties like this if needed:

```
$buildAppWorkdir["appname"] = $json.appname
$buildAppWorkdir["category"] = $json.category
```

If this is not what you wanted and if I'm on the right track, please tell me so I tune it up to your needs.